# How to avoid concurrent updates on gridview for a particular record?

Tags: asp.net

In Gridview, when user is updating on a record and how to restrict other user not to update on the same record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to "lock" records to one user at a time however that results in a very slow database, not to mention that it is simply not all that practical in real world situations. The better method to avoid concurrency issues is to capture the original values when the gridview is loaded and once an update statement or delete statement is run, the database rejects the command if the original values do not match. Take a look at the code below for this project I did a few weeks ago. Pay particular attention to the original values references.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechSupport_DataConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Technicians] WHERE [TechID] = @original_TechID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [Email] = @original_Email AND [Phone] = @original_Phone" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Technicians] ([Name], [Email], [Phone]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Phone)" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Technicians] WHERE ([TechID] = @TechID)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Technicians] SET [Name] = @Name, [Email] = @Email, [Phone] = @Phone WHERE [TechID] = @original_TechID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [Email] = @original_Email AND [Phone] = @original_Phone">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="TechID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_TechID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Phone" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_TechID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Phone" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After adjusting the sql statements then you just need some code to handle any database exceptions using event handlers such as "item inserted", etc. See the code below.

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" + "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            e.KeepInEditMode = true;
        }
        else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
            lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that product." + "<br />Please try again.";
        else
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void DetailsView1_ItemDeleted(object sender, DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" + "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
            lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that product." + "<br />Please try again.";
        else
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" + "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            e.KeepInInsertMode = true;
        }
        else
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to avoid concurrency errors at the database level, you would do that through the code you used to update the record.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195858/how-to-deal-with-concurrent-updates-in-databases) a good link on the subject.  There are lots of others, as well.

If what you mean is, "How can I prevent a user from even beginning to edit a record that someone else is in the process of updating in another GridView", that would be a lot more complicated.  There would be quite a few different ways to do it, but I think I would look at keeping a cache of the IDs of the records that are being updated, with some means for expiring entries (in the case where the user started editing but wandered off, suffered a systems failure, or otherwise never finished).