# How does MySQL handle concurrent inserts?

Tags: mysql

I know there is one issue in MySQL with concurrent SELECT and INSERT. However, my question is if I open up two connections with MySQL and keep loading data using both of them, does MySQL takes data concurrently or waits for one to finish before loading another?

I’d like to know how MySQL behaves in both cases. Like when I am trying to load data in the same table or different tables concurrently when opening separate connections.

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you post some code and ask for specific points in code?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you will create a new connection to the database and perform inserts from both the links, then from the database's perspective, **it will still be sequential**.

The documentation of [Concurrent Inserts for MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html) on the MySQL's documentation page says something like this:

> If **MyISAM** storage is used and **table has no holes**, multiple INSERT statements are queued and performed in sequence, concurrently with the SELECT statements.

Mind that there is no control over the order in which two *concurrent inserts* will take place. The order in this concurrency is at the mercy of a lot of different factors. To ensure order, by default you will have to sacrifice concurrency.

Comment: so what if it is same database but different tables ?

Comment: @user3360140: in that case the connections will not be competing to lock the table. Therefore they both will get the lock and will be able to insert to both tables at the same time.

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please update your answer as per my update? also, you mentioned,  "Concurrent insertions are still subject to concurrent_insert parameter. Make sure it is not set to 0"; can you please explain that a bit further? I know concurrent_insert has to be enabled for concurrent select and inserts; but how does it effect multiple parallel inserts (same table / different table)?

Comment: @user3360140: Updated. Sorry for the confusion there. Inserts will always be sequential. The `concurrent_insert` param doesn't change anything in that regard. It is about concurrent `SELECT` and `INSERT`.

Comment: Imagine I am inserting rows baed on primary key, say one thread is inserting rows whose keys lie in the range 1-100, another thread is inserting rows whose key lie in the range 200-300. If it was one thread, we would be sure that it will be sorted in order of the primary key which is an integer. But here, because they are concurrent, will it be guaranteed that the resulting rows will still be sorted according to primary key?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger: I don't think the insert will be sorted by primary key. There is no particular reason for it t be. However almost always there is an index on primary key. That index can be maintained as a self balancing tree.

Comment: If I add an index, will it ensure that even if the inserts are not consecutive, the data will be stored in a sorted manner (through clustered index) ?

Comment: And even though there is no index on the primary key I have added explicitly, say if I insert 2 before 1, but when I query `select all`, 1 comes before 2 in the result set. So I assume it is sorted internally during each insert. The same behaviour will surely hold true for concurrent inserts as well?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger: What are you really trying to achieve? Why is it a requirement for you to have data stored in a sorted manner? If you want 1 before 2 in the result set, a simple declarative way is to add an ORDER BY clause in your query.

Comment: Well, sorted primary key is critical to prevent fragmentation. A random set of non-consecutive integers is just like setting a GUID as primary key, it can cause heavy fragmentation.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger: Maintaining sorted primary key with concurrent and unsorted inserts will cause your inserts to limp. You will be effectively performing Insertion sort in this case. The fragmentation that you are worried about can be taken care of by (a) Caching in large RAM and (b) Proper indexing for fast retrieval.

Comment: Maybe I am asking a very basic question, but is above-mentioned statement stated for inserts, true for updates also? Are updates are also sequential?

Comment: @dhroove: [Updates have to be handled differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205379/1835769).

Comment: is this anyhow related to optimistic concurrency? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Answer (score 20):

### MySQL does support parallel data inserts into the same table.

But approaches for concurrent read/write depends upon storage engine you use.

#### InnoDB

MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables to support simultaneous write access by multiple sessions, making them suitable for multi-user, highly concurrent, and OLTP applications.

#### MyISAM

MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables, allowing only one session to update those tables at a time, making them more suitable for read-only, read-mostly, or single-user applications

But, the above mentioned behavior of MyISAM tables can be altered by [`concurrent_insert`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) system variable in order to achieve concurrent write. Kindly refer [to this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) for details.

Hence, as a matter of fact, MySQL does support concurrent insert for InnoDB and MyISAM storage engine.

Answer (score 7):

You ask about Deadlock detection, ACID and particulary MVCC, locking and transactions:

**Deadlock Detection and Rollback**

> InnoDB automatically detects transaction deadlocks and rolls back a
>   transaction or transactions to break the deadlock. InnoDB tries to
>   pick small transactions to roll back, where the size of a transaction
>   is determined by the number of rows inserted, updated, or deleted.
>   When InnoDB performs a complete rollback of a transaction, all locks
>   set by the transaction are released. However, if just a single SQL
>   statement is rolled back as a result of an error, some of the locks
>   set by the statement may be preserved. This happens because InnoDB
>   stores row locks in a format such that it cannot know afterward which
>   lock was set by which statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html

**Locking**

> The system of protecting a transaction from seeing or changing data
>   that is being queried or changed by other transactions. The locking
>   strategy must balance reliability and consistency of database
>   operations (the principles of the ACID philosophy) against the
>   performance needed for good concurrency. Fine-tuning the locking
>   strategy often involves choosing an isolation level and ensuring all
>   your database operations are safe and reliable for that isolation
>   level.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_locking

**ACID**

> An acronym standing for atomicity, consistency, isolation, and
>   durability. These properties are all desirable in a database system,
>   and are all closely tied to the notion of a transaction. The
>   transactional features of InnoDB adhere to the ACID principles.
>   Transactions are atomic units of work that can be committed or rolled
>   back. When a transaction makes multiple changes to the database,
>   either all the changes succeed when the transaction is committed, or
>   all the changes are undone when the transaction is rolled back. The
>   database remains in a consistent state at all times -- after each
>   commit or rollback, and while transactions are in progress. If related
>   data is being updated across multiple tables, queries see either all
>   old values or all new values, not a mix of old and new values.
>   Transactions are protected (isolated) from each other while they are
>   in progress; they cannot interfere with each other or see each other's
>   uncommitted data. This isolation is achieved through the locking
>   mechanism. Experienced users can adjust the isolation level, trading
>   off less protection in favor of increased performance and concurrency,
>   when they can be sure that the transactions really do not interfere
>   with each other.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_acid

**MVCC**

> InnoDB is a multiversion concurrency control (MVCC) storage engine
>   which means many versions of the single row can exist at the same
>   time. In fact there can be a huge amount of such row versions.
>   Depending on the isolation mode you have chosen, InnoDB might have to
>   keep all row versions going back to the earliest active read view, but
>   at the very least it will have to keep all versions going back to the
>   start of SELECT query which is currently running

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/17/innodbs-multi-versioning-handling-can-be-achilles-heel/

Answer (score 4):

### It depends.

It depends on the client -- some clients allow concurrent access; some will serialize access, thereby losing the expected gain.  You have not even specified PHP vs Java vs ... or Apache vs ... or Windows vs ...  Many combinations simply do not provide any parallelism.

If different tables, there is only general contention for I/O, CPU, Mutexes on the buffer_pool, etc.  A reasonable amount of parallelism is possible.

If same table, it depends on the indexes and access patterns.  In some cases the threads will block each other.  In some cases it will even "deadlock" and rollback one of the transactions.  Deadlocks not only slow you down, but make you retry the inserts.

If you looking for high speed ingestion of a lot of rows, see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  It lays out techniques, and points out sever of the ramifications, such as replication, Engine choice, multi-threading.

Multiple threads inserting into the same tables -- It depend a lot on the values you are providing for any `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` keys.  It depends on whether other actions are taken in the same transaction.  It depends on how much I/O is involved.  It depends on whether you are doing single-row inserts, or batching.  It depends on ...  (Sorry to be vague, but your question is not very specific.)

If you would like to present specifics on two or three designs, we can discuss the specifics.