# How do I lock a MySQL table for the current session?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, locking

All I read about table locks in MySQL concerns different sessions, so one session cannot interfere with another one. But what if I want multiple transactions from the *same* session to be mutually exclusive? `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` only locks certain rows but I want the whole table to be locked. 
In other words: If a specific transaction is running, no other transaction should be able to start, no matter which session it is from. When the first transaction finishes, the second one should start.

Comment: Have you considered `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

Comment: The same session cannot have multiple parallel transactions (MySQL doesn't even support nested transactions). Please clarify what you mean by that, e.g. what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe this subject will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473928/mysql-multiple-transactions-incrementing-same-row

As @Solarflare said, you can't have parallel transactions. So the following transactions will only work if the previous one is committed or roll back.