# How do I deal with concurrency problems using Yii2 and MySQL transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, yii2

**Overview**

Consider the following details:

1. We have a table named `user`. In it is a column named `wallet`.
2. We have a table named `walletAction`. We insert a new entry on each wallet action a user is doing. This table acts like some sort of logs in the database with some calculations.
3. We have a CRON command that does an update every `N` minutes. Each CRON action gets some data by using a standalone API and 'inserts' a new `walletAction` entry. At the sime time, it updates the `user`.`wallet`'s value.
4. A `user` can buy stuff from our site. When the `user` clicks the buy button, we insert a new `walletAction` entry and change the `user`.`wallet` column.

**Problem**

I am afraid that the *CRON update* and the *action of the `user` when they click the buy button* will happen at the exact same time causing the entries in the `walletAction` table to have wrong calculations.

I need some kind of 'lock' on the CRON update execution or something along those lines.

**Questions**

1. Should I be afraid of this situation?
2. How can I avoid this problem?
3. Can I avoid this trouble by using MySQL transactions?
4. What isolation level should I use and in which case should I use it? (In the CRON command or in the action of the `user` when they click the buy button?)

Comment: You seem to be at a loss for the term; you are worried about having **concurrency** problems.

Comment: [might be able to help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195858/how-to-deal-with-concurrent-updates-in-databases)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we don't have concurrency on `php` as is in `GO` or `Java`. You can implement some technical trick, but almost of them made new problems for you :). For solving your problem i suggest you to use `optimistic lock`. For more information you can see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#optimistic-locks.

Comment: I won't help because as far as I know it locks only on beforeSave till afterSave. So if I need change several tables(entries) it will be a problem because I need lock them all, not just 'one on update moment'. So it cannot help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case I would recommend to use [trasactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#specifying-isolation-levels) with the strongest isolation level `yii\db\Transaction::SERIALIZABLE`.
This level should prevent "phantom reads" and "non-repetable reads".

Moreover I recommend to use transactions always when you perform more than 1 related changes, because it helps to keep DB consistency. 
This may prevents problem when you get some PHP exception after successful inserting new rows into `walletAction`, but before `user.wallet` updating.